# looking at buy MacBook that needs OS installed

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm looking at getting a MacBook, and the seller did a Factory Reset and said it just needs the OS installed. Is there anything I should look out for?

Comment: Installing OS X is trivial and inexpensive if you need to reorder the DVD on older Macs. What are your concerns?

Comment: well I was wondering there was a problem with. if I should be concred because he did a factory reset and needed a OS install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An erase of the computer protects the seller from losing private data or giving away software that isn't licensed for resale.

Similarly, you should wipe the Mac to ensure no malware is installed. As with any used purchase, you need to do your work to ensure it's not stolen, or broken and feel comfortable with how to contact the seller in a week's time if the transaction wasn't as described.

If the deal is too good to be true, it may well be.

Comment: where can I get a OS for it

Comment: 1-800-my-apple would be a place to start. Once you know what OS comes with the Mac - you can see if a used copy is cheaper or if the Mac ships with internet recovery and you can simply re-download the OS from Apple without needing to order anything.

Answer (score 1):

Really, DON'T.

The Mac O/S is licensed to be used with a big dongle that prevents it being installed elsewhere. That dongle is called "A Macintosh."

Yeah, wipe the drive before selling. that is what they call "A Good Idea."

Just remember that a Mac with no O/S on it is a Mac that you can't really run basic diagnostics on:

Does it have the hard disk and RAM capacities as indicated?
Does everything work? (EG all the ports, WiFi, monitor, etc.)

So why didn't they at least reinstall from the media that came with the Mac. or from newer ones, install from the COMMAND-R, internet restore? It doesn't take long. And failing to do that makes me think (correct or not) that they may be trying to hid a problem.

Yeah you can bring an O/S install DVD with you and do some basic checking. or even TechTool Pro and sit there for an hour while it does a comprehensive check on all the hardware.

But really, when someone is selling you a Mac with no O/S installed, just say no.